# Can we use dynamic pipe?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I start two apps in linux such as A | B,so that the output of A will be redirected to B by pipe.
When i kill B,it will generate a SIGPIPE,and I want to keep A alive and restart B,so that the output of A can still be redirected to B.
How can I achieve it,dynamic pipe?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep the pipe open and restart `B` when it dies:

```
A | while true; do B; done
```